# How to differentiate two forms of percent in a grammar?

Tags: antlr4, grammar

I have two forms of "percent" that I need in a grammar:

```
PERCENT_1
    : 'PERCENT'
    ;

PERCENT_2
    : '%'
    ;
```

One is the word `PERCENT`, for example used with something like `LIMIT 10 PERCENT` and the other is the modulo operator. What might be a good way to differentiate these two things?

Comment: Are you asking for a suggested convention for naming terminal symbols? Or something else?

Comment: @rici yes, exactly.

Comment: It's totally up to you, of course, but I guess there are two styles, not exclusive: (1) Use `PERCENT_OP` or even `MODULO` for the operator; (2) use a consistent prefix like `TK_` for literal words (`TK_PERCENT` in this case, for the spelled out word.) I tend to use the `TK_` convention to avoid having my token names collide. (But I mostly work in C; I don't know if it's an issue for you.) That's probably more work at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is a keyword, the other an operator. I usually name keyword tokens `<name>_SYMBOL` and operators `<name>_OPERATOR` (see the [MySQL grammar](https://github.com/mike-lischke/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/frontend/src/parsing/mysql/MySQLLexer.g4)). Of course this is totally up to you, but should be consistently used throughout your grammar(s).